# Forecast multiple time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I want to predict the data consumption of each customer but the problem is that all the models do not give me what I want. Because at the beginning when there are not many customers the unit consumption is high but as soon as the number of customers increases then the consumption will stabilize for a good while then it increases but so much at the beginning there was a high consumption so my models do not give good results. The Question is how to correct the starting values ​​so that the model gives me what I want or is there a model to fix the minimum so that it starts to rise.

I want this:

[image]

not this:

[image: min]

Comment: Hi there! We do not have your data or the code you are using. We don't know which starting values you are talking about, which function you are applying them to, or really anywhere near enough information to help you here. Please edit your question to add this information. Thank you.

Comment: take a look at the `prophet`-package..